# Чередование положения картинки в div

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Никак не могу придумать, как сделать так, чтобы при выводе постов картинка была для четных постов слева, а для нечетных наоборот - справа. В одну строчку уже научился выводить. Вот структура вывода одного поста в html, все посты в lenta1:

```
<div class="lenta1">
<div class="im">image</div>
<div class="text">text</div>
<div class="clear"></div></div>
```

Если есть возможность на js, то тоже напишите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/465dst77/1/), все на чистом css.

Comment: Спасибо, это вертелось, но не было самой реализации.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите псевдокласс css **:nth-child(i)**

Вот [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child) подробно написано 
и даже с i играть не нужно, так как odd\even есть, то же самое можно и через JS оформить.

Думаю, это правильный путь: написать 2 стиля для odd/even, где img позиционировать, как надо вам (ну или float разный прописать).

И да, обверните **каждый отдельный пост в свой div** и именно им пропишите всего 2 стиля, для четного и нечетного div'a, тогда легче будет. Удачи!